# Is there a way to serialize only public fields if class has no attributes in Protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

Protobuf-net has an option to serialize public fields of the class

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Customer
{

}
```

To enable ProtoBuf to work for most DTOs I had to add this attribute to each class.
Is there a way to set it globally, so if class being serialized doesn't have any attributes like ProtoContract or DataContract, it will use "ImplicitFields.AllPublic" by default?

Comment: You can dom some Aspect oriented programming :-). and Inject the attribute to all public fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't currently supported. In v2, you *can*, however, tell it about types at runtime, via

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Customer), false).Add({fields});
```

but there isn't currently an option from there that accepts `ImplicitFields` (this is just an oversight, and will be added in a future build).

I have also had discussion with a few people about adding an event that is triggered the first time a new type is seen, that would allow you to do this by subscribing to an event. That has yet to be written, though.

Comment: Has this global `ImplicitFields` option since been added? Can't seem to find it in the API.

Comment: What about version 3?

Comment: @runxc1 no; it honestly doesn't seem a desirable feature to me